# Access to behavior property in viewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have added "DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior" behavior to xaml:

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="MessagesListView" Grid.Row="0"   Style="{StaticResource BasicDataGridStyleWithAutoHeight}" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MessagesView}}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                       GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler"   
                       IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolConverter}}" IsReadOnly="True"
                       SelectionMode="Extended">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

This is DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior class and "SelectedItems" property works properly. Depending on what is selected, this IEnumerable collection is populated.

```
public class DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
            => AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;

        protected override void OnDetaching()
            => AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;

        private void AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var array = new object[AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Count];
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CopyTo(array, 0);
            SelectedItems = array;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

        public IEnumerable SelectedItems
        {
            get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

[image]

I want to have access to this property in my viewModel to copy all selected items to clipboard and do not know, how to do it properly:

```
public class MessagesViewModel : DialogWindowViewModel, IMessagesViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<IEnumerable> SelectedItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IEnumerable>();

         public MessagesViewModel(ILoggingService loggingService, ILogger logger = null)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _loggingSvc = loggingService;
            CopyCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await CopyLog().ConfigureAwait(false));
        }

        public RelayCommand CopyCommand { get; }

        private async Task CopyLog()
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(FormatForClipboard(SelectedItems));
        }

        FormatForClipboard()
        {
        ...
        }   
}
```

Thank you for answer.

Comment: You have the `SelectedItems` in your viewmodel, which is via binding up to date!? Do work with this property. What is the problem?

Comment: In "DataGridSelectedItemsBehavior" class property is populated correctly, in viewModel this property is always null :(

Comment: Have you set(correctly) `DataContext` for the `DataGrid`? Otherwise your binding will not work.

Comment: I think so:
public MessagesPage(IMessagesViewModel messagesViewModel)
{
DataContext = messagesViewModel;
InitializeComponent();
MessagesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MessagesListView.ItemsSource);
Loaded += MyWindow_Loaded;
}

Comment: Is `DataGrid` directly in your `MessagesPage`? Are there maybe another container with changed `DataContext`?

Comment: Ok, it is now working. Thank you so much!